# Given that $(m+n)^2=2$ and $m^2+n^2=15$, find the value of $(m-n)^2.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to do? Please help. I've no idea, this is all what I know:

$(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$

So I know that $(a+b)^2=2$ and $a^2+b^2=15$, how to get $(a-b)^2$?

- so $(a+b)^2=2$ is useless, because it is not related to $(a-b)^2$
- I am able to get $2ab=2-15$ or $ab=-6.5$, but how is it useful to what I want to find?

Comment: .... and $(m+n)^2=m^2+2mn+n^2=2$ and $m^2+n^2=15$.  And $(m-n)^2=m^2-2mn+n^2$.  That's enough.  You can certainly figure out what $2mn $ is.  You don't have to figure out either m nor n.

Comment: @fleablood no my Math is (VERY) bad I need step-by-step that's why...

Comment: $(m+n)^2 = m^2 + 2mn +n^2 = (m^2 + n^2) + 2mn = 15 + 2mn$.  So $15+2mn = 2$.  So what is $2mn$?  An $(m-n)^2 = m^2 -2mn +n^2 = m^2 + n^2 - 2mn = 15 - 2mn$.  So again?  ... what is $2mn$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I) $$m^2 + n^2 = 15$$

II) $$(m + n)^2 = 2$$

$$m^2 + 2mn + n^2 = 2$$

$$(m^2 + n^2) + 2mn = 2$$

$$ 15 + 2mn = 2$$

$$2mn = -13$$.

So III)$$(m-n)^2 = m^2 - 2mn + n^2$$
$$ = (m^2 + n^2) - 2mn$$
$$=15 - (-13)$$
$$ = 28$$.

.....

It wasn't asked for but $2mn = -13$ so $m = \frac {-13}{2n}$

So $m^2 + n^2 = \frac {169}{4n^2} + n^2 = 15$

$4n^4 - 60n^2 + 169 = 0$

$n^2 = \frac {60 \pm \sqrt{60^2 - 4*169}}8$

$n^2 = \frac {60 \pm \sqrt{2924}}8$

$= \frac {30 \pm \sqrt{731}}4$

$n = \pm \frac{\sqrt{30 \pm \sqrt{731}}}2$

$m = \mp \frac {13}{\sqrt{30 \pm \sqrt{731}}}$

Which is obviously too absurdly complicated to be expected to solve.  So this is an example that one can solve general equaltions about $m^2 + n^2$ or $2mn$ without having to solve for $m$ and $n$ specifically.

Answer (score 3):

$m^2+n^2+2mn=2$

$m^2+n^2=15$

Thus $2mn=-13$

$(m-n)^2=m^2+n^2-2mn=13+15=28$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.* $(m-n)^2=2(m^2+n^2)-(m+n)^2$.

Comment: I'm confused by the hint...

Comment: @XPMai This is an identity. It holds for all $m,n$ (expand both sides and you'll see it). So, you can substitute the values of $m^2+n^2$ and $(m+n)^2$ into the right hand side to obtain the value of $(m-n)^2$ on the left hand side.

Comment: This is the way I did it - avoiding intermediate calculations (+1)

Comment: no... the identity is $(m-n)^2=m^2-2mn+n^2$...

Answer (score 1):

we get $$m^2+2mn+n^2=15+2mn$$ or $$(m+n)^2=15+2mn$$ from the first equation we get
$$-13=2mn$$ therefore $$m^2-2mn+n^2=15+13=28$$

Comment: how to get the $-13$?

Comment: from $$(m+n)^2=2$$ and $$2=15+2mn$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$(m-n)^2=m^2-2mn+n^2=m^2+2mn+n^2-4mn=(m+n)^2-4mn$

Now., can you figure out the value of $mn$ using what you know?

Comment: Sorry,I'm confused... what $-4mn$?

Comment: @XPMai I used the "trick" that one may always "add zero" and one may always "multiply by one" without changing anything.  What specific form zero looks like and what specific form one looks like is up to you.  I used "addition by zero" in this case as "addition by $4mn-4mn$" since adding and subtracting the same thing is the same as adding by zero.  To continue from where I left off, you just need to calculate what $-4mn$ is equal to by using what you were already given.  (*You were given two equations.  Subtract the one equation from the other to get the value of $2mn$*).